# jquery not working in user control page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my project i am using Chosen `jQuery plugin` for searching dropdownlist

in my `Master page` end of before body tag put the `css` and `jquery script` files

```
<link href="/assets/css/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/assets/css/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/css/chosen.jquery2.js"></script>
```

dropdown list i called class like below sample

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Dropworktype" runat="server" ***CssClass="chzn-select"*** AutoPostBack="True" >
                <asp:ListItem Value="0">-ఏ పని చేస్తున్నారు-</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="వ్యవసాయ కార్మికులు">వ్యవసాయ కార్మికులు</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="మత్స్య కారులు">మత్స్య కారులు</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="నేత పనివారు ">నేత పనివారు</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="కల్లు గీత కార్మికులు">కల్లు గీత కార్మికులు</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="కుమ్మరి / ఇటుక బట్టి ">కుమ్మరి / ఇటుక బట్టి</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="గొర్రెల కాపరి ">గొర్రెల కాపరి </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="వడ్రంగి / కంసాలి ">వడ్రంగి / కంసాలి</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="చర్మకారులు">చర్మకారులు</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="పూజారి">పూజారి</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="వ్యాపారి ">వ్యాపారి </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="తాపీ మేస్త్రి ">తాపీ మేస్త్రి </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="10">ఇతరములు </asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

choosen jquery search working fine in my page. But when i am using same in user control page its not working.

i dont know where is the problem in my page jquery problem or page problem

please help me thanks...

---

```
This is my User control page

<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Basic-Inser-Details.ascx.cs" Inherits="Grievance.User_Controls.Basic_Inser_Details" %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      // WRITE THE VALIDATION SCRIPT IN THE HEAD TAG.
      function isNumber(evt) {
          var iKeyCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
          if (iKeyCode != 46 && iKeyCode > 31 && (iKeyCode < 48 || iKeyCode > 57))
              return false;

          return true;
      }
    </script>

<link href="../assets/css/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../assets/css/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/css/chosen.jquery2.js"></script>


<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>


<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
   <div class="alert alert-error" id="diverror" runat="server" visible="false">
        <caption>
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                ×
            </button>
            <strong style="color:#fff; font-size:16px; font-weight:400; text-shadow:none;">అర్జీదారుడు గతంలో దాకలు చేసిన అర్జీ వివరాలు</strong> <a data-toggle="modal" href="#modal-table" style="color:#94210a; font-size:16px; font-weight:400; text-shadow:none; text-decoration:underline;">కొరకు ఇక్కడ క్లిక్ చేయండి </a>
        </caption>

    </div>




       <div class="alert alert-error" id="Adhererror" runat="server" visible="false">
        <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close">×</button>
        <strong style="color:#fff; font-size:16px; font-weight:400; text-shadow:none;">అర్జిదారుని వివరాలు ఆధార్ నుండి "101" వచ్చిన యెడల   <span style="color:#94210a; font-size:16px; font-weight:400; text-shadow:none; text-decoration:underline;"> ఉంది కాని తిసుకు రాలేదు </span> అనే ఆప్షన్ ఎంచుకోండి </strong>


    </div>






    <tr>
        <td width="21%"><span class="red">*</span> ఆధార్ కార్డు  
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator16" CssClass="error" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="aadhaselection"
    runat="server" ValidationGroup="basicinfo"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator15" CssClass="error" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="aadhaselection"
    runat="server" ValidationGroup="aadharinfo"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        </td>
        <td width="2%">:</td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="aadhaselection" runat="server" CssClass="border" ValidationGroup="basicinfo" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="aadhaselection_SelectedIndexChanged" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">ఉంది</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2"> ఉంది కానీ తీసుకురాలేదు</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">నమోదుచేసుకోలేదు</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>

        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="trtxtaadhar" runat="server" visible="false">
        <td><span class="red">*</span> ఆధార్ నంబర్:
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtAdherno" CssClass="error" SetFocusOnError="true"
    runat="server" ValidationGroup="basicinfo"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" controltovalidate="txtAdherno" CssClass="error" SetFocusOnError="true" validationexpression="^[0-9]{12}$" ValidationGroup="basicinfo"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" controltovalidate="txtAdherno" CssClass="error" SetFocusOnError="true" validationexpression="^[0-9]{12}$" ValidationGroup="aadharinfo"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td width="25%">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdherno" CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="12"  ValidationGroup="basicinfo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
              <cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender1" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="txtAdherno"         
    FilterType="Numbers"  />
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <asp:Button ID="btbaadher0" runat="server" class="btn btn-success" OnClick="btbaadher_Click" Text="ధృవీకరించండి" ValidationGroup="aadharinfo" />

        </td>
    </tr>

</table>

<table id="aadhartable" runat="server" class="table table-bordered" visible="false">

     <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="9" style="background: #5c7399; color: #fff;">అర్జీదారు వివరాలు</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td width="14%"><span class="red">*</span> అర్జీదారుని పేరు
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtname" CssClass="error" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="basicinfo"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
        <td width="2%">: </td>
        <td width="26%">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server" CssClass="telugu form-control"  Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>

            <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        </td>

        <td width="12%"><span class="red">*</span> c/o పేరు 
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtcareof" CssClass="error" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="basicinfo"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        </td>
        <td width="2%">:</td>
        <td width="28%">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtcareof" runat="server" CssClass="telugu form-control" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>

            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="6" align="center" valign="top" style="width:150px;">
            <asp:Image ID="imgpic" runat="server" Style="height: 155px; width: 130px;" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnpic" runat="server" />
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><span class="red">*</span> వయస్సు
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revage" runat="server" controltovalidate="txtage" CssClass="error" SetFocusOnError="true" validationexpression="^[0-9]{2}$" ValidationGroup="basicinfo"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtage" CssClass="error" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="basicinfo"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtage" runat="server" MaxLength="2" CssClass="form-control" onkeypress="javascript:return isNumber (event)" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>        

            <asp:Label ID="lblage" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        </td>

        <td><span class="red">*</span> లింగము
             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator21" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlgender" CssClass="error" InitialValue="0" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="basicinfo"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>

        <td>:</td>

        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlgender" Visible="false" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="0">లింగము</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">పురుషుడు</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">స్త్రీ</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">ఇతరులు</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:Label ID="lblgender" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>

        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><span class="red">*</span> జిల్లా
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator19" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlditric" CssClass="error" InitialValue="-జిల్లా-" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="basicinfo"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>     <td>:</td>

        <td>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlditric" Visible="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlditric_SelectedIndexChanged"  AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:Label ID="lbldistric" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hidndistricid" runat="server" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdpincode" runat="server" />
        </td>

        <td><span class="red">*</span> మండలం  
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="dropmandal" CssClass="error" InitialValue="-మండలం-" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="basicinfo"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="dropmandal" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="form-control"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropmandal_SelectedIndexChanged" Visible="false"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:Label ID="lblmandal" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkmandal" runat="server"  OnClick="lnkmandal_Click"><img width="22" src="/images/edit-btn2.png" /></asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="red">*</span> పంచాయతి / టౌన్ :   
             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ControlToValidate="droptwon" CssClass="error" InitialValue="-రెవెన్యూ గ్రామం-" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="basicinfo"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="droptwon" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Visible="false"></asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:Label ID="lbltown" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lblpancht" runat="server"  OnClick="lblpancht_Click"><img width="22" src="/images/edit-btn2.png" /></asp:LinkButton>

        </td>

        <td><span class="red">*</span> హాబిటేషను 
             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txthabitation" CssClass="error" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="basicinfo"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txthabitation" runat="server"  CssClass="telugu" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>


             <asp:Label ID="lblhabitation" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="red">*</span> బిల్డింగ్ నం
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtbuildno" CssClass="error" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="basicinfo"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtbuildno" runat="server"  CssClass="form-control" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
            <cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="ftbe" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="txtbuildno"         
    FilterType="LowercaseLetters, UppercaseLetters,Custom, Numbers"  ValidChars="-/"/>
            <asp:Label ID="lblbuilding" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        </td>

        <td><span class="red">*</span> వృత్తి 

             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator10" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Dropworktype" CssClass="error" InitialValue="0" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="basicinfo"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td>
              <asp:DropDownList ID="Dropworktype" runat="server" CssClass="chzn-select" AutoPostBack="True" >
                <asp:ListItem Value="0">-ఏ పని చేస్తున్నారు-</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="వ్యవసాయ కార్మికులు">వ్యవసాయ కార్మికులు</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="మత్స్య కారులు">మత్స్య కారులు</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="నేత పనివారు ">నేత పనివారు</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="కల్లు గీత కార్మికులు">కల్లు గీత కార్మికులు</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="కుమ్మరి / ఇటుక బట్టి ">కుమ్మరి / ఇటుక బట్టి</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="గొర్రెల కాపరి ">గొర్రెల కాపరి </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="వడ్రంగి / కంసాలి ">వడ్రంగి / కంసాలి</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="చర్మకారులు">చర్మకారులు</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="పూజారి">పూజారి</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="వ్యాపారి ">వ్యాపారి </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="తాపీ మేస్త్రి ">తాపీ మేస్త్రి </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="10">ఇతరములు </asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>


            <asp:TextBox ID="txtoccupation" runat="server" CssClass="telugu form-control"   Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>


        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                                     <td><span class="red">*</span> ఫోను. నం 
                                         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator12" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtmoble" CssClass="error" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="basicinfo"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                         <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="txtmobilevalidation" runat="server" controltovalidate="txtmoble" CssClass="error" SetFocusOnError="true" validationexpression="^[0-9]{10}$" ValidationGroup="basicinfo"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                                                            </td>
                                     <td>:</td>
                                     <td>
                                         <asp:TextBox ID="txtmoble" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" visible="false" MaxLength="10"  onkeypress="javascript:return isNumber (event)" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtmoble_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <br /> <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator12" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtmoble" ErrorMessage="సరైన నంబరు ఇవ్వగలరు" CssClass="error" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="basicinfo" ValidationExpression="^[7-9][0-9]{9}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                         <asp:Label ID="lblmobile" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                         <asp:LinkButton ID="hyperedit" runat="server" Visible="false" OnClick="hyperedit_Click"><img width="22" src="/images/edit-btn2.png" /></asp:LinkButton>
       </td>
                                         <td>ఓటరు కార్డ్ నం.<%--(EPIC)--%></td>
                                     <td>:</td>
                                     <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtvoter" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                     <td>E-mail ID</td>
                                     <td>:</td>
                                     <td>
                                         <asp:TextBox ID="txtmailid" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>   



                                         <asp:RegularExpressionValidator   
            ID="regtxtmailid"  
            runat="server"    CssClass="error"
            ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"  
            ControlToValidate="txtmailid"  
            ErrorMessage="దయచేసి మీ E-mailid సరిచుసుకోండి!"  
            >  
        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                     </td>

                                         <td><span class="red">*</span> కులం
                                             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server" ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList3" CssClass="error" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="basicinfo"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                         </td>
                                     <td>:</td>
                                     <td colspan="2">
                                         <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList3"  runat="server"  CssClass="border" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                                             <asp:ListItem>ఎస్.సి.</asp:ListItem>
                                             <asp:ListItem>ఎస్.టి.</asp:ListItem>
                                             <asp:ListItem>బి.సి.</asp:ListItem>
                                             <asp:ListItem>మైనారిటీ.</asp:ListItem>
                                             <asp:ListItem>ఇతరులు.</asp:ListItem>
                                         </asp:RadioButtonList>                                     </td>
                                 </tr>
                             <tr>
                                     <td><span class="red">*</span> అర్జీ కేటగిరి  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" InitialValue="0" ControlToValidate="ddlcate" CssClass="error" SetFocusOnError="true"
                                        runat="server" ValidationGroup="basicinfo"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator> </td>
                                     <td>:</td>
                                     <td>
                                       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcate" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlcate_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
                                       <asp:ListItem Value="0">అర్జీ కేటగిరి</asp:ListItem>
                                       <asp:ListItem Value="1">వ్యక్తి గతం–ఆర్ధికం   </asp:ListItem>
                                       <asp:ListItem Value="2">వ్యక్తి గతం–ఆర్ధికేతరం</asp:ListItem>
                                       <asp:ListItem Value="3">సామాజికం- ఆర్ధికం</asp:ListItem>
                                       <asp:ListItem Value="4">సామాజికం- ఆర్ధికేతరం</asp:ListItem>


                                   </asp:DropDownList>     


                                     </td>

                                         <td>కాలపరిమితి
                                                              </td>
                                     <td>:</td>
                                     <td colspan="2"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbltimescale" Text="0" ></asp:Label>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lbltext" runat="server" Text="రోజులు"></asp:Label>
                                                                            </td>

                                 </tr>
     <tr >
                                      <td>   వార్షిక ఆదాయం            
                                      </td>
                                     <td>:</td>
                                     <td colspan="6">  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbnewfinance" runat="server" CssClass="border" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                                    <asp:ListItem>60,000 లోపు</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>60,000 -75,000</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>75,000 పైబడి</asp:ListItem>                              
                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                                                          </td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr runat="server" id="traadhernote" visible="false">
                                      <td> <span class="red">*</span> ఆధార్ చిరునామాలో మార్పు ఉందా?           
                                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator13" runat="server" ControlToValidate="rbincome" CssClass="error" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="basicinfo"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                      </td>
                                     <td>:</td>
                                     <td colspan="6">
                                         <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbincome" runat="server" CssClass="border" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbincome_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                             <asp:ListItem Value="1">ఉంది </asp:ListItem>
                                           <asp:ListItem Value="2" >లేదు</asp:ListItem>
                                         </asp:RadioButtonList>                                     </td>
                                 </tr>
                             </table>

<table runat="server" id="trprathuthanivasam" visible="false" class="table table-bordered">


    <tr>

        <td width="21%">  <span class="red">*</span> జిల్లా
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator23" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlprentdistric" CssClass="error" InitialValue="-జిల్లా-" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="basicinfo"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>     
           <td width="2%">:</td>
        <td width="22%">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlprentdistric" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlprentdistric_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
        <td width="13%">  <span class="red">*</span> మండలం  
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator14" runat="server" ControlToValidate="dropPramandal" CssClass="error" InitialValue="-మండలం-" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="basicinfo"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
        <td width="2%">:</td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="dropPramandal" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="form-control" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropPramandal_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td>  <span class="red">*</span> పంచాయతి / టౌన్ :
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator17" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DroppraTown" CssClass="error" InitialValue="-రెవెన్యూ గ్రామం-" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="basicinfo"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DroppraTown" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td>  <span class="red">*</span> హాబిటేషను  
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator20" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtprahabitation" CssClass="error" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="basicinfo"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtprahabitation" runat="server" CssClass="telugu form-control"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td><span class="red">*</span> బిల్డింగ్ నం    
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator22" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtbuilding" CssClass="error" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="basicinfo"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td colspan="4">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtbuilding" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox><cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender2" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="txtbuilding"         
    FilterType=" LowercaseLetters, UppercaseLetters,Custom, Numbers"  ValidChars="-/"/>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="modal-table" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-header no-padding">
        <div class="table-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            దాకలు చేసిన అర్జీ వివరాలు
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body no-padding">

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">

        <button class="btn btn-small btn-danger pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">
            <i class="icon-remove"></i>
            Close</button>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

On each different page that you open in a browser you have to include the plugin and (before calling the plugin) jquery library too. So if your master page and user control page are two differnt pages just replicate the same headers in both.

```
<link href="/assets/css/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/assets/css/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/css/chosen.jquery2.js"></script>
```

Also note that, based on the directory structure of your page, if the user control page is not in the same folder of the master page you will need to adapt the path to the included files.

Comment: could you edit the question to show how the user control page code looks like?